# Electromagnetic wave in a prism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics

Imagine an electromagnetic plane wave entering perpendicular to one of the faces of a prism with the form of a triangle rectangle, which is made of a certain material of refraction index $n$. The wave enters the prism, reflects on its hypotenuse with an angle $\beta$, and exits the prism through the other side.

How does the angle of the polarization of the wave $\theta$ and the index of refraction $n$ of the prism, affect in general the final intensity $I_{out}$ and phase difference of the wave $\Delta\phi$ in comparison with the initial intensity $I_0$ (assuming the incident wave has no phase difference)?

In other words, how could one express or develop a expression of the type

$$I_{out}=I_0f(n,\theta)$$

where $f(n,\theta)$ is a function of $\theta$ and $n$, and then find the phase difference $\Delta\phi$ for the elliptical final wave in terms of the internal reflection angle $\beta$ and the diffraction index $n$:

$$\Delta\phi=g(n,\beta)$$

I tried using boundary conditions for dielectric media, but they don't seem to really lead anywhere. What other concepts do you think could be used?

Edit: I managed to find the intensity of the emergent wave using Fresnel equations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations)in the following way:

Let's take a linear combination of the parallel ($p$) and perpendicular ($s$ components of the electric field with respect to the plane of incidence:

$$\vec{E_0}=\vec{E_p}+\vec{E_s}$$

We'll focus only on the amplitudes (since the intensity doesn't depend on the phase difference anyways).

1) Transmission from air to prism

$$|t_p|=|t_s|=\frac{2}{n+1}$$

2) Reflection from air to prism

$$|r'_p|=|r'_s|=1$$

3) Transmission from prism to air

$$|t''_p|=|t''_s|=\frac{2n}{n+1}$$

Therefore, the final magnitude of the field $\vec{E_3}$ is:

$$|\vec{E_3}|=(\frac{2}{n+1})(1)(\frac{2n}{n+1})|E_0|$$

Since the intensity is proportional to the square magnitude of the field, we see that the initial intensity is:

$$I_0=k|\vec{E_0}|^2$$

And the final intensity is:

$$I_f=k|\vec{E_3}|=\left((\frac{2}{n+1})(\frac{2n}{n+1})\right)^2k|E_0|^2=\frac{16n^2}{(n+1)^2}I_0$$

**However...**

Now, I have no idea how to find the phase difference. If I'm right, the only phase change occurs during the internal reflection, but using Fresnel coefficients gives an extremely complicated expressions where it's impractical to extract the needed angle.

Comment: Calculate the problem for each of the three propagating polarisation states.

Comment: Thanks, I did find the solution for the intensity by considering each transmission and reflection in the waves propagation, I'll post the solution briefly. However, what I couldn't find was how did the phase change in comparison with the initial phase.

Comment: To do that you should compute the actual propagation, I'm not sure how you calculated the propagation of intensity, that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @MJC thanks I did that and managed to find the solution for the intensity. However, I'm still stuck on finding the phase difference, as computing the actual propagation doesn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: You cannot properly compute the propagation without the phase.

Comment: Actually I mean the intensity. At the end I managed to find the solution, I'll post it later as an answer for further reference.